# Why does Mathematica get the infinite sum of this representation of the taylor series of $\cos^2(x)$ wrong?

Tags: bugs, series-expansion

**Bug introduced in 12.0 or earlier, persisting through 13.2 or later**

---

Mathematica correctly identifies this sum as $\cos(x)$:

```
Sum[((-1)^n x^(2 n))/(2 n)!, {n, 0, Infinity}]
```

Mathematica also correctly identifies this product of sums as $\cos^2(x)$:

```
Sum[((-1)^i x^(2 i))/(2 i)!, {i, 0, Infinity}] Sum[((-1)^j x^(
   2 j))/(2 j)!, {j, 0, Infinity}]
```

However, when rearranged as this, Mathematica suddenly fails by finding $\cos^2(x) - \frac{1}{2}$ instead of $\cos^2(x)$:

```
Sum[((-1)^i x^(2 i))/(2 i)!*((-1)^j x^(2 j))/(2 j)!, {i, 0, 
  Infinity}, {j, 0, Infinity}]
```

It is interesting to note that it finds this sum to be the same as the above product for any finite number of terms, and only fails in the limit.

Is there a good reason for this happening?

Comment: What is even more interesting is that if you define: `test[order_] := 
 Factor[Sum[((-1)^i x^(2 i))/(2 i)!, {i, 0, 
      order}] Sum[((-1)^j x^(2 j))/(2 j)!, {j, 0, order}] - 
   Sum[((-1)^i x^(2 i))/(2 i)! ((-1)^j x^(2 j))/(2 j)!, {i, 0, 
     order}, {j, 0, order}]]` and then you do `Limit[test[order], order -> Infinity]` or `Series[test[order], {order, Infinity, 2}] // Normal // 
  Factor // TrigReduce` you get a `0` as expected. But `test[Infinity] // TrigReduce` yields `1/2`.

Comment: `Sum[Sum[((-1)^i x^(2 i))/Factorial[2 i] ((-1)^j x^(2 j))/
    Factorial[2 j], {i, 0, Infinity}], {j, 0, Infinity}]` also works.

Comment: Also, starting the sums from 1 rather than 0 correctly gives `(Cos[x]-1)^2`.

Comment: So this would be a bug in Mathematica itself?

Comment: The option `Method -> "IteratedSummation"` fixes it. As for the original, if the answer is wrong, how is that not a bug? Report to WRI.

Comment: This has been noted in-house. Definitely not the desired behavior.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau do you think we should add the bugs header and tag?

Comment: @bmf Yes, please add them. (Tagging I can manage on a good day, but I actually don't know how to add that as a header.)

Comment: @DanielLichtblau, in the "header" (page title), the tag that has overall the most questions on SE is displayed. So you can't really "choose" which one will be displayed, it is chosen automatically among the provided tags.

Comment: @user58955, are you sure? I get [the same result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJ1ea.png) as in v12.3 or 13.3.

Comment: @Domen Sorry, I was mistaken. The problem persists in v14.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Expanding on the comment by @Goofy and after reading the [**docs**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sum.html) we see that:

1. `"ParallelFirstToSucceed"`
   try each method in parallel until one succeeds
2. `"ParallelBestQuality"`
   try each method in parallel and return the best result
3. `"IteratedSummation"`
   use iterated univariate summation

So, if we do

```
Sum[((-1)^i x^(2 i))/(2 i)!*((-1)^j x^(2 j))/(2 j)!, {i, 0, 
  Infinity}, {j, 0, Infinity}, Method -> "ParallelFirstToSucceed"]
```

or

```
Sum[((-1)^i x^(2 i))/(2 i)!*((-1)^j x^(2 j))/(2 j)!, {i, 0, 
  Infinity}, {j, 0, Infinity}, Method -> "ParallelBestQuality"]
```

or

```
Sum[((-1)^i x^(2 i))/(2 i)!*((-1)^j x^(2 j))/(2 j)!, {i, 0, 
  Infinity}, {j, 0, Infinity}, Method -> "IteratedSummation"]
```

And if we don't want to use any `Method` in the `Sum`

```
Limit[Sum[((-1)^i x^(2 i))/(2 i)!*((-1)^j x^(2 j))/(2 j)!, {i, xx, 
   Infinity}, {j, xx, Infinity}], {xx -> 0}]
```

or

```
Normal@Series[
  Sum[((-1)^i x^(2 i))/(2 i)!*((-1)^j x^(2 j))/(2 j)!, {i, xx, 
    Infinity}, {j, xx, Infinity}], {xx, 0, 0}]
```

all yield

> `Cos[x]^2`

Comment: What does "best" mean in this context? Also, if all three of these options work, what is the failing default?

Comment: @SamuelMartineau I am not sure what `best` means. I am pretty confident, though, that this should answer the latter question you posed; namely what is the failing condition.

Comment: The thing I find peculiar is that both "FirstToSucceed" and "BestQuality" work when ran in parallel…

Answer (score 2):

Vs 6  gets the correct result, but Wolfram $\alpha$ decides, too, that
$$\sum_{m,n=0}^\infty \frac{  (-1)^{n+m} x^{2m+2n} }{(2n)!(2m)!} \quad \ne \quad \sum_{m=0}^\infty\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{  (-1)^{n+m} x^{2m+2n} }{(2n)!(2m)!}\right) $$

Inspection of the double sum shows weight 1/2 only at $(n,m)=(0,0)$, but only for upper limits $m,n=\infty$

```
      Sum[((-1)^(m + n) x^(2 m) x^(2 n))/((2 n)! (2 m)!), 
          {n, 0, \[Infinity]}, {m, 0, \[Infinity]}] // TrigReduce
```

$$\frac{1}{2} \cos (2 x)$$

```
      Sum[Sum[((-1)^(m+n) x^(2m) x^(2n))/((2n)!(2m)!),
               {n,0,\[Infinity]}], {m,0,\[Infinity]}]//TrigReduce
```

$$\frac{1}{2} (\cos (2 x)+1)$$

Today all infinite sums with 2-term recursions are expressed as hypergeometric series, a bit dangerous an attempt because of their complex definitions with cuts on the real line:

```
 ds= Assuming[0 < x < \[Pi]/2, 
     Sum[((-1)^(m + n) x^(2 m) x^(2 n))/((2 n)! (2 m)!), 
      {n, 2, \[Infinity]}, {m, 2, \[Infinity]}] // TrigReduce]
```

$$\begin{align}&\frac{113 x^{10} \, _3F_4\left(2,2,\frac{9}{2};1,\frac{11}{2},\frac{11}{2},6;-\frac{x^2}{4}\right)}{5443200}+\frac{x^{10} \, _4F_5\left(2,2,2,\frac{9}{2};1,1,\frac{11}{2},\frac{11}{2},6;-\frac{x^2}{4}\right)}{272160}\\&+\frac{x^{10} \, _5F_6\left(2,2,2,2,\frac{9}{2};1,1,1,\frac{11}{2},\frac{11}{2},6;-\frac{x^2}{4}\right)}{4082400}-\frac{8 x^{10} \, _3F_4\left(2,2,\frac{9}{2};1,\frac{11}{2},\frac{11}{2},6;-x^2\right)}{127575}\\&-\frac{x^{10} \, _4F_5\left(2,2,2,5;1,1,\frac{11}{2},6,6;-\frac{x^2}{4}\right)}{302400}-\frac{x^{10} \, _5F_6\left(2,2,2,2,5;1,1,1,\frac{11}{2},6,6;-\frac{x^2}{4}\right)}{4536000}\\&-\frac{57}{5} x^6 \, _1F_2\left(\frac{5}{2};\frac{7}{2},\frac{7}{2};-\frac{x^2}{4}\right)+\frac{32}{5} x^6 \, _1F_2\left(\frac{5}{2};\frac{7}{2},\frac{7}{2};-x^2\right)\\&-\frac{1796}{9} x^4 \, _1F_2\left(\frac{3}{2};\frac{5}{2},\frac{5}{2};-\frac{x^2}{4}\right)+\frac{32}{9} x^4 \, _1F_2\left(\frac{3}{2};\frac{5}{2},\frac{5}{2};-x^2\right)+5632 \text{Ci}(x)+\frac{797 x^6}{5400}-\\&\frac{131 x^4}{4}+2366 x^2+\frac{1711}{2} x^2 \cos (x)-30 x^2 \cos (2 x)-\\& -5632 \log (x)-\frac{10771}{2} x \sin (x)+65 x \sin (2 x)  \end{align}$$

The nested sum is

```
   ns=Assuming[0 < x < \[Pi]/2, 
      Sum[Sum[((-1)^(m + n) x^(2 m) x^(2 n))/((2 n)! (2 m)!), 
             {n,  2, \[Infinity]}], 
        {m, 2, \[Infinity]}] // TrigReduce]
```

$$\frac{1}{4} \left(x^4\ - \ 4 x^2\ + \ 4 x^2 \ \cos (x)-8 \cos (x)\ + \ 2 \cos (2 x)+6\right)$$

On this level the lowest terms are equal

```
 Series[ds-ns,{x,0,2}]

  O[x^3]
```

and a plot shows identity, but an equality test seems to be to complex for the current versions, aborted after some minutes.

Only the case of lower bound 0 is showing a difference in the constant term.

Comment: Interesting… Btw, what is this "Vs 6" you are referring to?

Comment: @SamuelMartineau Version 6.